# jquery toggle 3 state with initial state

Tags: jquery

jQuery toggle() support multiple states, and it cycles through as many as you give it

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

> If more than two handlers are provided, .toggle() will cycle among all
>   of them. For example, if there are three handlers, then the first
>   handler will be called on the first click, the fourth click, the
>   seventh click, and so on.

The following code works great, cycling through all three states.

```
$('#tag').toggle(function() {
  //set cssClass to 'on'
  //remove all other classes
}, function() {
  //set cssClass to 'off'
  //remove all other classes
}, function() {
  //set cssClass to 'none'
  //remove all other classes
});
```

My question is about the fact that on inital page load, the class is being set on the #tag by the backend but when clicking the tag toggle() starts the cycle from the first toggle state of  'on' regardless of initial state.

I suppose what I am looking for is a smart toggle that goes to the next state based on an option for the current state passed in.

I may be adding four states, so I do not want complex if else statements.

n.b The class setting and removing is just an example. I am doing other things. Please do not give adding and removing classes examples - Although you can check the class to find the initial state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you will need to do a hack into jQuery, which is not polite for sure, but works.

I took a look into jQuery source code and this is what it basically does:

1. Generates a new unique id and stores it as a property named `guid` in your first function
2. Stores index of the last function which is called in `jQuery._data(element, 'lastToggle'+guid, index)`
3. Toggles through your functions using `lastToggle` value and your function array

So in order to change the toggle index all you need is to read the `guid` from your first function and set your desired value with jQuery._data on the element.

I've made you a simple example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/2gJdG/

Here's the gist:

```
var fn1 = function (){
    console.log(1);        
};

$('button').toggle(fn1, function (){
    console.log(2);
}, function(){
    console.log(3);
}, function(){
    console.log(4);
});

jQuery._data($('button').get(0), 'lastToggle' + fn1.guid, 2);
```

As you can see by clicking on the button it will call the third function and so on.
You will need to define at least your first function in a variable to access it's properties later.

And remember that this is just a hack and someday might break by upgrading your jQuery.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I am wondering if we could make a jQuery plugin state does this same behavior. called toggleState()